# javascript audio pause previous playing audio when current playing in react

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a simple function in react which plays the audio..

```
handlePlayMusic() {

    this.audio = new Audio(music)
    this.audio.play()
}

handleStopMusic() {

    this.audio.pause()
}
```

When I play the new music i. e. the value of `music` in `Audio(music)` is changed new music is played but previously played music countinues to play. I want it to be stopped when I play new music..

Any help ??

Comment: You have not written any code to make that happen ....

Comment: How should I check.. when I play new music there is new instance in `this.audio` that means old one should not be played right ?

Comment: No, It will create new instance of Audio....

Comment: then how to destroy the old one ?? can you help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Stop the earlier instance of `this.audio` before playing it!

```js
var obj = {
  handlePlayMusic: function(music) {
    try {
      this.audio.pause();
      this.audio.currentTime = 0;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    this.audio = new Audio(music);
    this.audio.play()
  },
  handleStopMusic: function() {

    this.audio.pause()
  }
};
obj.handlePlayMusic('audio/audio.mp3');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/yuL3uw0j/)(Let audio get loaded first!)